# How to use ant variable in batch?

Tags: ant, batch-file, argument-passing

Hi all this is my maven comd to upload a file

```
mvn -e -s C:\settings.xml deploy:deploy-file -Dfile=D:\abc.exe -DgroupId=Agent -DartifactId=Instal -Dversion=1.2.3 -Dpackaging=exe -DuniqueVersion=false -DrepositoryId=releases -Durl=http://xyz:8081/internal/
```

i have placed this command in a batch file which i am calling from ant using `EXEC task` only problem is `file=D:\abc.exe` will always change,so i want to pass this from ant to batch and use it at `file="ARGUMENT FROM ANT"` can someone tell me how can i do it...in ant the file name is always stored in `${FILENAME}`.

Comment: You could consider using the Maven ANT task to deploy your file.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Use arg values like this :

```
<exec executable="cmd">
    <arg value="/c"/>
    <arg value="thebat.bat"/>
    <arg value="${FILENAME}"/>
</exec>
```

then retrieve it here in your bat file :

```
set myfile=%1
[...]
mvn -e -s C:\settings.xml deploy:deploy-file -Dfile=%myfile% -DgroupId=Agent -DartifactId=Instal -Dversion=1.2.3 -Dpackaging=exe -DuniqueVersion=false -DrepositoryId=releases -Durl=http://xyz:8081/internal/
```

check it there : http://ant.apache.org/manual/Tasks/exec.html